# converting from HTML to Wordpress.. not sure why CSS styling was lost/isn't working?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I built a site in HTML/CSS, and everything was to my liking. However, in the conversion from HTML to Wordpress(WP), the CSS styling seems to have been lost. I'm new to this, so it's difficult for me to pinpoint what's going on..

The `#main article <p>` section doesn't seem to be following the `#main article p {float: right; margin-top: -85px; margin-left: 230px; padding-left: ; width: 403px;}` parameters. Any ideas on what has happened?

```
<div id="main">
        <article>


            <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="headline">
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div><!-- end headline -->

            <div class="postinfo">
                <ul>
                    <li>Posted by <?php the_author(); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_date(); ?></li>
                    <li>tags: <a href="#">cool</a>, <a href="#">awesome</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end postinfo -->

            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        </article><!-- end article -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else :?>
                <p>I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>


    </div><!-- end main -->

#main {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 315px;
    margin-top: 310px;
}
#main article .postinfo {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: ;
    width: 150px;
}

#main article p {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -85px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    padding-left: ;
    width: 403px;
}
```

EDIT: here it is live [here it is live](http://www.achenn.byethost7.com/)

[image: ideal]

Comment: are you sure the css file is being references correctly? (Not in `/styles/mycss.css` but thinks its in `/blog/styles/mycss.css`?) Or are your styles in the page's source?

Comment: First check you desired css is applying or not. Secondly By seeing this code we cant say that your css rules are clashing or not.. It is better to use firebug to see the problem in real time or show us the real time problem. please

Comment: @BradChristie all of the other styling seems fine, it's just the content area that's gone awry.

Comment: And I don't like the `padding-left: ;` but that could be just me.

Comment: @MrLister Yea, I noticed that right after I posted this question and removed it. Thank you for pointing it out though.

Comment: @HappySingh here it is live- http://www.achenn.byethost7.com/

Comment: i can solve your issues with css but can you provide me the screenshot or image what exactly you want because your coding and structure is bit different in so many ways and layout is also some what different.

Comment: @user1255049: Could you provide your working static HTML page? This would make things a lot easier. By the way, did you notice that you load the stylesheet twice in your Wordpress version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<p></p>` tags around `<?php the_content(); ?>` since that will be generated within the content, and you are basically wrapping that in a paragraph.

It is a also good idea to have the static html files open and your Wordpress project side by side, so you can inspect elements on both and make sure your selectors match. This usually helps me figure out when I'm missing the selector for some reason.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: removed the `<p>` around the `<?php the_content(); ?>`- problem persists.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to target `.entry-content, .entry-summary`. Maybe replace your `#main article p` with that and see if it gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: .entry-content and .entry-summary must be the Wordpress generated classes someone above mentioned? I'll try using those and see how it goes, thank you.

Comment: using either of those tags didn't seem to work, but here is the live site- http://www.achenn.byethost7.com/

Comment: OK. It looks like Main needs a width of probably around 350px. Also you should be clearing your floats. You can add the psuedo `:after` element to your classes with `a clear:both` that should help the overlapping stuff. [Clear Fix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think WordPress automatically generates the `<p>`s so it might just be an issue of double `<p><p>`.

There are also some generated classes that WordPress uses, you could try using your browsers Inspect function, identifying the classes that are being generated, and explicitly styling them the way you want them to look.

Also, it's kind of an obvious thing, but make sure you're using a CSS reset, it could make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the "article" tag, try wrapping  like this:

```
<div class="post_entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

then replace the css reference with

```
#main .post_entry p
```